# How can I render different layouts of same component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am building an Audio Player and I want it to have different layouts. I achieved what I wanted but I am wondering if there is a better way:

So render method inside my PlayerComponent looks like this:

```
// ** PlayerComponent.js

render() {
    const { playerStatus, duration, position, track, volume, isLoaded, queue } = this.state;
    const showDock = { height: '100px', margin: '0px'};
    const audioPlayerProps = {
      ...
      playerStatus: playerStatus,
      duration: duration,
      position: position,
      track: track,
      volume: volume, 
      isLoaded: isLoaded,
      queue: queue,
      showDock: showDock,
      ...
    };

      switch( this.mode ) {
        case 'Single':
          return <SinglePlayer {...audioPlayerProps} />
        case 'Playlist': 
          return <PlaylistPlayer {...audioPlayerProps} />
        case 'Dock': 
         return <DockPlayer {...audioPlayerProps} />
      }
    }
```

I conditionally render player depends of the current player mode. I am passing props from PlayerComponent to different player templates.

My example player template:

```
// ** SinglePlayerTemplate.js

import ...
import ...
import ...
import ...

const SinglePlayerTemplate = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {props.isLoaded && props.queue.length !== 0 ? (
        <div className={`AudioPlayer${props.mode}`}>
          <Thumbnail />
          <div className={`AudioPlayer${props.mode}-controls`}> 
            <Track track={props.track} />
            <PlayerNavigation
              ... 
              togglePlayer={props.togglePlayer}
              playerStatus={props.playerStatus}
              skipToPreviousTrack={props.skipToPreviousTrack}
              track={props.track}
              disabledNext={props.disabledNext}
              disabledPrev={props.disabledPrev}
              mode={props.mode}
              ...
            />
            <BrandLogo />
            <PlayerOptions 
              ...
              setVolume={props.setVolume}
              setSpeed={props.setSpeed}
              ...
            />
            <Link />
          </div>  
        </div>
      ) : (
        <div className={`AudioPlayer${props.mode}-loader`}>Loading...</div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

export default SinglePlayerTemplate;
```

And all of the templates share same code when I am creating other mode of the player, it just feels redundant. Because if I will have 10 different modes of the player and I want to pass one extra prop to the player I need to write it in 10 different places. Wonder if there is a better way of rendering same components with a different layouts.

Thanks

Comment: Can you give a link to your code(github)?

Answer (score 0):

It's always a good practice to re-use React Components. For your use case, you can create a **Players Component** and pass **props** specific to your requirement, like etc. 
type of player - single, playlist etc.

You can then handle these props in the Player Component and write the Use-Case Specific code accordingly. This will help to re-use the component and avoid redundancy.